# HTML5 Validation Warning is not shown on Chrome Extention

Tags: google-chrome-extension

On my webpage I have a form. I am using html 5 Validation.

```
 <input type="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" id="sign-in-email" required>
```

This validation is working fine on Browser but when I open same page using Chrome Extention Popup, this validation is not displaying any message (Though it is not stopping the user from submitting form.)

[image: Validation on Browser]

Comment: And have you [debugged it](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging)? This usually has to do with [extension CSP](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy).

Comment: @Xan what should I debug exactly??

Comment: You should also change sing in to sign in

Answer (score 0):

The content security policy for Chrome Apps restricts you from doing the following:

You can't use inline scripting in your Chrome App pages. The restriction bans both  blocks and event handlers ().
You can't reference any external resources in any of your app files (except for video and audio resources). You can't embed external resources in an iframe.
You can't use string-to-JavaScript methods like eval() and new Function().

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/apps/contentSecurityPolicy/